# Finding peers to write a math paper? (soft question)

Tags: soft-question, education

I'm an engineering major who wants to combine my findings in a field of combinatorics, but i haven't had too many friends from my math courses to share it with. I was thinking of visiting my old university and contacting the math department, but is there an easier way like a forum of like minded mathematicians who want to write topics worldwide? Just in case they are locally not specialized in this topic. Sorry if this an obvious question, I'm mainly asking for knowledge of specific organizations or forums

Comment: The traditional way for like-minded mathematicians to meet is through conferences. If you can find a conference on combinatorics, for example the [54th SEICCGTC](http://www.math.fau.edu/combinatorics/index.php) which will be held in Florida, March next year. Registration is expensive (255 USD for the early bird registration), but this is the way that mathematicians tend to meet. Contacting your old university might be fruitful, but it depends on someone there either knowing the topic you want to research well, or personally knowing someone else who does, and being willing to introduce you.

Comment: I would say google for professors who have worked on that specific branch, and send emails to them, asking for help / introducing someone.